# Como converter String em Double usando JSP FMT EL

Tags: java, jsp

Ola
Tenho uma string 9,9, eu gostaria de converter em 9.9 e em double para fazer soma

Atualmente eu uso assim:

```
<c:set var="media" value="0" />
//onde a funcao.valor é uma string 9,9
<c:set var="ontem" value="${ontem + funcao.valor}" />
```

Agradeço antecipadamente

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi rsrs
Usei a função: fn:replace

Então ficou assim:

```
<c:set var="media" value="0" />
//onde a funcao.valor é uma string 9,9
<c:set var="ontem" value="${ontem + fn:replace(funcao.valor,',','.')}" />
```

Ai deu certo rsrs

Comment: Não sei se está correto, mas deu certo rsrs

Comment: dei uma editada, realmente tinha algo de errado na parte fn:replace(funcao.valor,',','.') onde eu tinha colocado aspas duplas (") ai troquei para aspas simples (')